# Finding a more effective algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity, pseudocode

I have the following pseudocode:

```
for i = 0 to n-1
    Add the numbers A[0] thru A[i].
    Store the result in B[i].
```

The worst case time complexity of this must be O(n) since assigning a new element to B is just O(1) and the code runs the for loop n times. Is that correct?

My task is to find a more effective algorithm than the one above. I mean O(n) is already pretty fast so i don't know how I would find a more effective algorithm. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This algorithm runs in O(n²), since the "Add the numbers A[0] thru A[i]" runs in O(n) time.

Comment: Why is this tagged python? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not a site for solving your homework, please share your attempt if you're failing in completing it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have to add all the numbers from `A[0]` to `A[i]` *in each iteration*, then it's `O(n^2)` complexity. For example, in Python:

```
# O(n^2) solution

a = [2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 9, 8]
b = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(i+1):
        sum += a[j]
    b.append(sum)
```

What you can do to make this `O(n)` is to calculate the current sum using the previous results, like this:

```
# O(n) solution

a = [2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 9, 8]
b = [a[0]]

for i in range(1, len(a)):
    sum = b[i-1] + a[i]
    b.append(sum)
```

The result will be the same in both cases, but the second version will have `O(n)` complexity:

```
b
=> [2, 5, 10, 17, 18, 27, 35]
```

Answer (score 3):

The `O(n)` algorithm for this would be something like:

```
sum = 0
for i = 0 to n-1
    Add A[i] to the sum
    Store the sum in B[i].
```

There is no way to find an algorithm for this problem with the runtime complexity less than `O(n)` because you NEED to visit all the items in array in order to calculate the sum of all of them. This statement applies to a case when you don't have any preliminary knowledge about the array structure.

Comment: Oh, i thought that was the same as the given code. But now when you pointed it out I think i understand, they are adding A(0)+..+A(i) every time and not storing it in any variable. Follow up question: when calculating time complexity O(n) (where n is the number of operations) is every addition and assignment counted as an operation? Would for example i = 2+3 count as two operations, one addition and one assignment?

Comment: @KarlKarlsson - answering to your question, yes - BUT - when calculating the runtime complexity of algorithm - you don't need to end up with particular number, all you need is some abstract formula - so you can generally compare algorithms. In your case the complexity is O(1).  Usually you don't need constants or you can omit some variables which value can be neglected in regard to others. Anyway there are books which describe the process of finding runtime complexity of the algorithms.